# load method in THREE.FileLoader only gets the content of index.html

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've set up a very small browser project using `create-js-app`. I try to load a file called `test.txt` located in my `src` directory.

Following is the content of my `main.js`:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';

const loader = new THREE.FileLoader();

loader.load(
    "test.txt",
    function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    function (xhr) {
      console.log(
        "Loading file : " +
          (xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 +
          "% loaded"
      );
    },
    function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
```

When running my site in Chrome, I get the content of my `index.html` file instead of `test.txt`. I spent some time trying to understand this with no success.

I get this result no matter which file path I specify as first argument of `loader.load()`, I can even specify a file that is not existing.

Has anybody already faced this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: I'm using Parcel as the bundler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue comes down to internal details of [create-js-app](https://github.com/michalkvasnicak/create-js-app), and different web applications may host static resources (i.e. images and other assets that are *not* compiled source code) in different ways. But generally speaking, the `src/` directory is not hosted/deployed/served on the website. If your application has the structure [shown here](https://github.com/michalkvasnicak/create-js-app/tree/master/packages/js-app-template-universal) then you probably want to put the .txt file into the `public/` directory instead.

Requesting any file that cannot be found at the given URL might be giving you the index page instead, depending on how your site is set up by create-js-app.

Comment: I tried setting up a project using only npm, and this worked. Thanks a lot for your precise informations :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating the answer above: I'm using Parcel. I fixed my project by adding this line:

```js
url = require('test.txt')
```

The `require` function makes the browser import the txt file, and it returns the hashed url of the stored file. All I had to do next was to call

```js
loader.load(url, ... )
```